# Mutating table in SQL for a specific case of update

Tags: triggers, oracle10g

I have create a trigger for table stock

The schema of the table is as follows:

```
create table stock(item_code varchar2(2) primary key, p_qty number(2),s_qty number(2));
```

The Trigger is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_STOCK BEFORE UPDATE OF S_QTY ON STOCK FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    V_P STOCK.P_QTY%TYPE;
    V_S STOCK.S_QTY%TYPE;
    V_I VARCHAR2(2);
BEGIN
    V_S:=:NEW.S_QTY;
    V_I:=:NEW.ITEM_CODE;
    SELECT P_QTY INTO V_P FROM STOCK WHERE ITEM_CODE=V_I;
    IF V_S>V_P THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20400,'SOLD QTY CANNOT EXCEED PURCHASED QTY...');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Now every time I execute an update query, it says the table is mutating and flags the following error:

```
update stock set s_qty=2 where item_code='i4'
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04091: table HR.STOCK is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "HR.TR_STOCK", line 8
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'HR.TR_STOCK'
```

Any help with this specific problem?

Comment: You can't select from a table you're updating in a trigger. This might be indicative of a flaw in your data model... There doesn't seem to be a need to do anything like this though. Why don't you just use the `if` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to query the `STOCK` table.  Simply compare the `:NEW.P_QTY` and `:NEW.S_QTY` fields directly

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_STOCK BEFORE UPDATE OF S_QTY ON STOCK FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
    IF :new.s_qty > :new.p_qty THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20400,'SOLD QTY CANNOT EXCEED PURCHASED QTY...');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

You really should consider using a database constraint to implement this logic, in which case you wouldn't need the trigger at all.

```
ALTER TABLE hr.stock 
ADD CONSTRAINT stock_ck1
CHECK (
  s_qty <= p_qty
)
```

Triggers have many drawbacks compared with constraints:

- Triggers do not account for existing data rows, constraints can do this if you desire.
- A `FOR EACH ROW` trigger has to context-switch between the SQL engine and the PL/SQL engine for *every row*, which increases the overhead of the `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement running. This adds up as your number of rows increases.
- Oracle can use constraints when optimising your SQL statements (it knows that a `WHERE` clause that violates a `CHECK` constraint will never return any rows without needing to inspect the rows).

If you're using the trigger to provide an error message, you should really consider moving this into your application logic, with constraints as a safeguard.